# R: How to sample a different column for each row of a dataframe?

Tags: r, sample

I want to sample a different column for each row of a dataframe using differing weights. I have tried a few things but have not been successful, including looking up similar questions. I am presenting a mock DF and expected output below.

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- mdply(data.frame(mean=c(10, 15, 12, 24)), rnorm, n = 5, sd = 1)
df1
```

I want a vectorized solution (hopefully) to sample one column from V1 to V5 for every row. The weights for the sampling are the values in each cell from V1 to V5 for the row in question. The actual dataframe could have a couple million rows. A sample output is shown below.

```
f_col <- c(10,15,12,24)
sampled_column <- c("V3", "V1", "V5", "V5")

output_df1 <- data.frame("mean" = f_col, "result" = sampled_column)
output_df1
```

Comment: Just use `sample(names(df1)[2:6], nrow(df1), replace = TRUE)`  If it needs to be different, use `replace = FALSE`

Comment: Thanks Akrun. Can you please clarify where is the weights vector being declared and how do I declare the number of samples.

Comment: You say that you want one value per row, but next you talk about number of samples. Could you please clarify? You want for the fourth row 4 samples for instance? Does the row need to be replicated for each sample?  And about the weights, you mean that for the first row `V2` should be more likely to be extracted than `V4`?

Comment: One value per row refers to one column for each row. Yes, the fourth row should have four samples. I can just repeat the row as you suggest.  Weights refer to the values from column to V1 to V5 for each row. I have edited my question to address the confusion and make it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @MD_1977 -shouldn't "*sample one column from V1 to V5 for every row.*" be removed from the question then?

Comment: I yet need to sample just one column from V1 to V5 for every row using the values found in those cells. Thx

Comment: @MD_1977 - I really can't think of a clever way to do this that isn't going to be horribly slow, as you're essentially taking a `sample` for every row with a different set of `prob=`abilities for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [sample](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/sample) you can use *prob* to weight your sample probability. To make this for every row you can use [apply](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.0/topics/apply).

```
output_df1 <- data.frame("mean"=df1$mean, "result"=apply(df1[,-1], 1, function(x) {sample(names(x), 1, prob=x)}))
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. I will test it for run times, but this is great.

Comment: Hope it is also performant enough. For 10000 rows it needs on my pc ~ 0.1 second.